# Excel parse cell containing comma-space separated list and use each value as index

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel Sheet1,ColumnA is

```
1) 3, 2, 4
2) 1
```

The numbers refer to row numbers in Sheet2,ColumnB, which contains identifiers

```
1) foo
2) bar
3) eggs
4) sausage
```

What I should end up with is a column in Sheet 1, which contains

```
1) eggs, bar, sausage
2) foo
```

I'm pretty sure I can do this with a Python script, however it's preferred to do it in Excel. Unfortunately, I hardly know a thing about VBA.

Text to columns won't do: you can't target to a new sheet, but a cell in Sheet1ColumnA may contain any number of items.

Edit: VLOOKUP won't work here, as it looks up by cell *contents*. Here, I want to lookup by cell *reference*. INDEX would do, if I could get it to iterate over many comma-space-separated values in a single cell. I need to first parse the values in the cell, and then use some sort of INDEX to find the corresponding lookup value for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This VBA code will do the trick:

```
Public Function mysearch(value As String)
    Dim myrows() As String
    myrows = Split(value, ",")
    result = ""
    For i = LBound(myrows) To UBound(myrows)
        a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(myrows(i), 2) 'The first 2 is the number of sheet and the last 2 is the column.
        result = result & a & ","
    Next i
    result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    mysearch = result
End Function
```

Go to macro / VBA with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. Under ThisWorkbook insert a module and paste the code on the right side.

If your reference data is in sheet1 column A, then in cell B1 put `=mysearch(A1)`and if the data is in column B of Sheet2 you will get the result.

Comment: Thank you! That's just right. Confusingly, sheets can be called sheet1 but be numbered sheet3, but now I got that right it works like a charm. Many thanks again!